# ImportError:How to import function or class from parent directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, import, package

I am trying to import a class from parent directory to my script but I receive `attempted relative import with no known parent package`error, I have searched everywhere in the internet but still cannot fix the error. Here is my package structure:

```
A/
  a.py
  __init__.py
  B/
    __init__.py
    c.py
```

Now assume I have **class1** inside `a.py` module and I am trying to import it in the `c.py` module. I have tried:

```
from ..A.a import class1
```

But i get above error message I have tried to add the A folder to `sys.path` but still the same error. Can anyone explain how I can import a package from a function or class from parent directory to subdirectory (like from `a.py` to `c.py`)

Comment: The short version is that the `A` folder needs to be in the list of paths that Python searches for modules and packages. Please see the linked duplicate for a thorough overview.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is my extending the path in the `c.py` file by appending it. Below is an example of this:

**a.py** (example module in the parent directory)

```py
class class1:
    def __init__(self):
        print("This worked!")
```

**c.py** (example file invoking a.py in the parent directory)

```py
# By importing the sys module, you can change many
# things including the system environment.
import sys
sys.path.append("../")

# Once you've added the parent directory, you can freely
# import as you would have normally.
from a import class1
instance = class1()
```

The reason why your `..` didn't work is because imports starting with `.` or `..` are for importing from within things being imported (the way I understand it). An example of this to use your example would be to add a `d.py` alongside `a.py` which could be imported from `a.py` by using `from .d import *`.

Comment: It did not work it says ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package. is it different if I am running it in jupyter notebook like c.ipynb

Comment: @user59419 did you try changing `from ..A.a import class1` to `from a import class1` ??

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Comment: If you can try running it in a script to make sure it works that'll help. Also make sure you're running all the blocks and re-running them @user59419 - it's hard to offer any advice outside of "make sure the environment is ok" since that path error means the same code is running and you haven't changed it